# Maintain data in different domains in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain, session-cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have a small requirement that I want to send some data to **www.example.com** and at the same time  I want to get the data from **www.example.com**.

**Example** I want to search by email in **www.mydomain.com**, if result not found, I want to search the email address in **www.otherdomain.com**. from there I want to redirect to **www.mydomain.com** and keep the data what I used in email textbox.

I know that we can do it by using query string. is there any best solution to implement this requirement?

Comment: how you are searching the email in www.mydomain.com ? post any code

Comment: here searching means, verifying the email id in DB if not find , i will pass it to www.otherdomain.com. from that i have a back button , when i click back button it should redirect to www.mydomain.com with email id.